# Is it possible to change default time 10 seconds for restart policy of docker containers?

Tags: docker, containers

Here's Docker's official content related to 'Restart Policy'.

> Restart policy details
>
> Keep the following in mind when using restart policies:
>
> A restart policy only takes effect after a container starts successfully. In this case, starting successfully means that the container is up for **at least 10 seconds** and Docker has started monitoring it. This prevents a container which does not start at all from going into a restart loop.
>
> If you manually stop a container, its restart policy is ignored until the Docker daemon restarts or the container is manually restarted. This is another attempt to prevent a restart loop.
>
> Restart policies only apply to containers. Restart policies for swarm services are configured differently. See the flags related to service restart.

Does anyone know how to change 10 seconds value that waiting for avoiding a restart loop in Docker Environment ?

I want to make my app containerized to restart at least 60 seconds running not 10 seconds.